# how to create makefile in python without packages

Tags: python, linux, makefile

i want to create makefile with pythons codes
like it allow in c++

it's example in c++

```
    g++ main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp -o hello
all: hello

hello: main.o factorial.o hello.o
    g++ main.o factorial.o hello.o -o hello

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

factorial.o: factorial.cpp
    g++ -c factorial.cpp

hello.o: hello.cpp
    g++ -c hello.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *.o hello
```

how to make the same with pythons files?

i have 3 files:
hello.py , main.py , gui.py

I havent to use any packages

Comment: What do you want to do with your python files? You don't need to compile python before you can use it like you do with C++. That's what all those lines you listed are doing, compiling c++ source into a runnable binary (and cleaning up).

Comment: it's my homework. i want to compile all files. is it real with python files? i have example for c only

Comment: You don't compile python files. You just run them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally in Python you would write a [`setup.py` file](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) rather than a `Makefile`. This will take care of [building and installing](http://docs.python.org/2/install/) your package for you.

You can get closer to a C++ binary by packing your Python program with something like [`Py2Exe`](http://www.py2exe.org/) or [`PyInstaller`](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). These put all the dependencies needed to run your program into a single executable that is probably as close as you'll get to something like the G++ output from compiling a C++ program.

Answer (score 0):

I advice to read the chapter about *nix Python packaging in [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596515829.do). It is very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to compile Python files yourself. The Python runtime will do that automatically for you when the code is executed on an as-needed basis.

If you want to share Python code with someone else, you really just need to put all the files into a ZIP archive or tarball.